# Word Wrapping does not working with UILable in Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, word-wrap, ios-autolayout

I have set the Lines and Line Break at storyboard. But still not working.
[image: pic1]

After that I set the `preferredMaxLayoutWidth` for the label also not working for the word wrap.
[pic2][2]

I am using Auto layout at storyboard.

[image: pic3]

Comment: You set height for your label?

Comment: @Anand i using auto layout so the height is not set by me

Comment: Then you can try with number of lines = 0 and line break word wrap from story board and try without any code, Just pass inside your string, as per your #pic 1.

Comment: @Anand it is not working.

Comment: @Anand I have upload the new picture as pic3

Answer (score 0):

Multiline label you can do this way from **Storyboard**..

Make @IBOutlet of your label and pass your string inside label.

[image]

[image]

### or  can try with code also

```
var label:UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(10
    ,100, 300, 40));
label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center;
label.numberOfLines = 0;
label.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(16.0);
label.text = "First label\nsecond line";
self.view.addSubview(label);
```

Comment: you use auto layout also?

Comment: Yes it is the good way to make your layout, simple and easy to use try it.

Comment: but somehow my project still not support multiline

Comment: try these links best for you 1) http://www.appcoda.com/self-sizing-cells/ , 2)https://www.raywenderlich.com/129059/self-sizing-table-view-cells          You can learn from here multiline label.

Comment: By follow that two link, still cannot work with my project. dunno what happen

Comment: I don't know whats wrong with you. check properly steps and then try this.